# Java Enum in constructor cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, constructor, enums

```
public static enum enuGender{
    MALE,
    FEMALE,
    UNKNOWN
}

public enuGender gender;

//&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& Constructors &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
public Athlete(String firstName, String lastName, int age, enuGender gender) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
}
```

I have this code in an "Athlete" class, however when I try to instantiate an athlete in my main class like so:

```
Athlete ath = new Athlete("Jim", "Denver", 33, enuGender.MALE);
```

I am told the enuGender cannot be resolved to a variable. Can I not pass an enum value in the constructor??

Comment: As an aside, you should capitalize the first letter of the Enum type to follow naming standards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably the `enuGender` enum is nested within the `Athlete` class.  To refer to that enum from outside that class, you must specify the enclosing class name.  Try

```
Athlete ath = new Athlete("Jim", "Denver", 33, Athlete.enuGender.MALE);
```

The alternative would be to pull that enum declaration out of the `Athlete` class so that specifying the enclosing class name would be unnecessary.

Also, enum names follow Java conventions for class names; `Gender` is a better name.

Comment: Thanks for editing the naming suggestion in to your answer.